# Why can't I see the "Generate constructor" in Quick Actions in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

According to the [Visual Studio Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/csharp/refactoring) of C#. The "Generate constructor" option should be shown. [image].

However, it isn't shown in my case.[image]
About my VS code
[image]
I have installed and enabled extension like C#, C# Dev Kit, IntelliCode for C# Dev Kit. how should I fix this?

Comment: Does it work if you make those members public and/or properties?

Comment: What version of VS are you on?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever no, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Charlieface my vs code version are 1.86.2

Comment: Have you installed the [C# Dev Kit](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csdevkit)?

Comment: @GuruStron yes, I installed C# dev kit.

Comment: Do you have sln/csproj files in the opened structure? Try adding sln and csprojs and opening root folder which contains the sln file.

Comment: I think it will suggest a constructor when { get; set;} is after each property member